# Is possible to build a ROM with no facility to turn off GPS?

Tags: android, gps

I have this idea stuck in my head. How would you go about making a custom Android ROM with the GPS toggle unavailable ?

Comment: Is it possible?  Sure.  How would you do it?  Get the source tree and search for anything related to GPS or location, then take time to understand each part you find enough to decide if you should disable / fake out that particular piece of code, or leave that in and disable other parts.

Comment: When people build devices with GPS always on, its#s time to remember science fiction films of the 70ies where people use alu-foil to shield their brains. Then it would be time to use Alu-foil to shield GPS from mobile, e.g with a alu-foil phone cover.

Comment: Ofcourse you can do it as @ChrisStratton stated but i for one will not install that rom :P

Comment: what if I put the rom on a tracking device ?? would u want people to turn it off ?

Comment: Hope this link help you: [Tutorial: How To Building a Custom ROM - Android Internals](http://www.newtechie.com/2014/02/tutorial-how-to-building-custom-rom.html)

Comment: @jagzviruz Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: nopes.. gave up on it.